# Force mod_speling to use https

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, elastic-load-balancer, mod-speling

We are using the mod_speling in one of our projects which worked fine for years. However, recently we have moved to AWS cloud and hidden our instances behined an elastic load balancer. As the load balancer behaves as a reverse proxy, it also terminates SSL traffic. However, mod_speling doesn't know that and if there's a spelling issue to fix, it redirects a request to http:// instead of https:// .

How can I force mod_speling to use https? I've X_FORWARDED_* flags set and HTTPS set to "on" as well. The mod probably uses a SCRIPT_URI flag, but I'd rather not overwrite it as it doesn't feel like a good way to do this.

We are using Apache 2.4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enforce the **schema** (https) via your **ServerName** at your **vhost**, it will work as long as you are browsing via balancer which terminates SSL.

```
ServerName https://www.example.com
```

See more about [ServerName directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername)